# Hibernate query cache concurrency strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, concurrency

Do Hibernate cache concurrency strategies apply to its query cache too (e.g. a cacheable query gets some scalar data, and then two queries concurrently modify that scalar data)? If not, what happens with concurrent updates (or read/updates) for queries? If yes, how to specify them for query cache?

Comment: a good article in this context: http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is the following.

A timestamp cache keeps track of the last update timestamp for each table.

Each time a cachable query is executed and that the results are in the query cache, Hibernate checks the the timestamp of the query results is bigger (more recent) than the update timestamp of each table concerned by the query. If bigger, then the results are not stale, and the cached results are returned. If lower, then the cached results are potentially stale, and the query is executed against the database.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that query cache itself is never updated, but only invalidated, thus avoiding any concurrent update issues?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the cache deals with concurrent updates to the cache. But it's a cache accessed from multiple threads. I guess that synchronization and concurrent collections are used. You don't really have to care.

Comment: Well, for 2nd level cache, strategies like nonstrict-read-write and read-write behave differently and affect performance. So I want to know if similar things apply to query cache too, affecting its performance. Hence this question.